# Application terminated at middle

Tags: objective-c

Here My problem is when Im running my build in the device sometimes my application is    terminated at middle with displaying the message in the console as:

```
Program received signal:   "0".
warning: check_safe_call:could not restore current frame
```

Can anyone help why this was happening like this? Anyones's help will be appreciated.

Thank you,
    Monish Kumar.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like crash caused by low memory. Try to implement `-applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:` in your application delegate and free unnecessary resources there.

Comment: I tried to implement the -applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning method in application delegate but its showing the warning as:
NSObject may ot respond to '-applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning'

Comment: @Vladimir/@monish: It's `-applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:`, with a colon.

Answer (score 0):

This is very possibly caused by an infinite loop which is causing you to run out of memory and the debugger can't unwind the stack because there's too much recursion.

Set a breakpoint in the debugger at some point directly preceding the crash and then step through the operations in your code to find where the problem is occurring.

Comment: Actually I donno where the application crashing then where should I have to set the breakpoint?